# pagination and search in the same ruby method

Tags: ruby, ransack, pagination

I have the following method in my products controller...  the search and paginate seem to be working, but not playing along together.  Search is still returning all results, and paginate shows the navigation bar, but that's about it.

```
def index

#ransack
@search = Product.search(params[:q])
@products = @search.result

#paginate
@product = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

end

Answer (score 1):

ok, I solved my own problem.

@products = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page] , per_page: 10)